# The newtx isn't compatible with pifont?

Tags: fonts, symbols, newtx

I need the number of the footnote to be circled.

The following works well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
%\usepackage{newtxtext} 
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\ding{\numexpr171+\value{footnote}}}
\begin{document}
foo\footnote{bar}.
\end{document}
```

But if I uncomment `\usepackage{newtxtext}` the output appears like

foo①

That is, the circled 1 is not a superscript. It works well if I use `txfonts` package.

Comment: Yes newtx redefines `\@makefnmark` in a way that is problematic in some cases. You can restore the original definition with `\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother`. But I think this should also go as bug report to the author.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed! The package defines `\@makefnmark` so that it use specialized superscript numbers. There should at least be a package option for not changing the default `\@makefnmark`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for pointing out what causes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes newtx redefines `\@makefnmark` in a way that is problematic in some cases. You can restore the original definition with `\makeatletter \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}} \makeatother`. But I think this should also go as bug report to the author.