# Footnote in minipage wit newtxtext misses mark

Tags: footnotes, minipage, newtx

With the [`newtxtext`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newtx) LaTeX package, footnotes inside a minipage miss the mark.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={6cm,4cm},margin={2mm,2mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

This a paragraph\footnote{A footnote inside a paragraph} with a
footnote.

\vfil

\framebox{
\begin{minipage}[b]{4cm}
  This a minipage\footnote{A footnote inside a minipage} with a
  footnote.
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

This seems to happen only when the `newtxtext` package is used.

How to fix this?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104531/the-newtx-isnt-compatible-with-pifont

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
[...]
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{%
   \ifx\thefootnote\orig@footnote 
      \orig@makefnmark
   \else
      \hbox{\sustyle\hspace*{.04em}\thefnnote}%
   \fi}
\makeatother
[...]
```

looks like a bug ...

Comment: and is doing what? Do you not think a little explanation would be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

The `newtxtext` package redefines `@makefnmark`, but forgets to check for the `minipage` footnotes. This is to be considered a bug (see [The newtx isn't compatible with pifont?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104531/the-newtx-isnt-compatible-with-pifont))

A fix for this is either to restore the original definition or add a check for `minipage`. Note the difference in the typesetting of the numeric footnote numbers.

### Adding a check for `minipage` footnotes

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={6cm,4cm},margin={2mm,2mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{%
  \ifx\thefootnote\orig@footnote
    \ifx\@footnotetext\@mpfootnotetext
      \orig@makefnmark
    \else
      \hbox{\sustyle\hspace*{.04em}\@thefnmark}%
    \fi
  \else
    \orig@makefnmark
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This a paragraph\footnote{A footnote inside a paragraph} with a
footnote.

\vfil

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{4cm}
  This a minipage\footnote{A footnote inside a minipage} with a
  footnote.
\end{minipage}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

### Restoring the original definition of `\@makefnmark`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={6cm,4cm},margin={2mm,2mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\makeatletter
\let\@makefnmark\orig@makefnmark
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This a paragraph\footnote{A footnote inside a paragraph} with a
footnote.

\vfil

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{4cm}
  This a minipage\footnote{A footnote inside a minipage} with a
  footnote.
\end{minipage}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In fact I first came across this bug with the `tcolorbox` package. Then I tried other environments and found the same behaviour with `minipage`. I have used `minipage` in the question because it is more used (I suppose). Will the fix for the minipage work with `tcolorbox`?